# No tests found in class "AlliancesObjectTest" when PHPUnit testing

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm keep getting `No tests found in class "AlliancesObjectTest".` I tried it to run on vm and my machine but it doesn't work.

This are the contents of `tests\AlliancesObjectTest`

```
<?php

use \phpunit\framework\TestCase;

class AlliancesObjectTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function testPushAndPop()
    {
        $stack = [];
        $this->assertEquals(0, count($stack));

        array_push($stack, 'foo');
        $this->assertEquals('foo', $stack[count($stack)-1]);
        $this->assertEquals(1, count($stack));

        $this->assertEquals('foo', array_pop($stack));
        $this->assertEquals(0, count($stack));
    }
}
```

Contents of `phpunit.xml`

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./tests/phpunit.php">

    <testsuite name="unit">
        <directory>./tests</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>./src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/logs/clover.xml"/>
    </logging>

</phpunit>
```

contents of `tests\phpunit.php`

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Full response in terminal:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/xxxxxxx$ phpunit -v
PHPUnit 5.4.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.0.2-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 with Xdebug 2.4.0RC3
Configuration: /home/vagrant/xxxxxxx/phpunit.xml

W                                                        1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 225 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

There was 1 warning:

1) Warning
No tests found in class "AlliancesObjectTest".

WARNINGS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Warnings: 1.

Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... done
```

Comment: You do not need the `@test` annotation when the name of the method is prefixed with `test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPUnit 5.4.4 Version fixed this.